# unable to install libjpeg-turbo-progs package

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, yeoman

I am getting error on installation of libjpeg-turbo-progs such as

> sudo apt-get install libjpeg-turbo-progs

and it gives output as

> Reading package lists... Done
>     Building dependency tree
>     Reading state information... Done
>     E: Unable to locate package libjpeg-turbo-progs

I have also tried

> sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: apt-get install libjpeg-turbo8 maybe?

Comment: This also gives me same error as.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libjpeg-turbo8

Comment: Ok there is no libjpeg-turbo in lucid: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libjpeg&searchon=names&suite=lucid&section=all but libjpeg-turbo is a replacement for `libjpeg-progs`. Maybe thats the package you need.

Comment: I have tried
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-progs
and its working fine.

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you need to install JPEGTran because of Yeoman. I have the same error on Ubuntu 11.04 server.

Changing the package name from `libjpeg-turbo-progs` to `libjpeg-progs` installed JPEGTran correctly:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-progs
```

http://wtanaka.com/node/7988

Answer (score 0):

You should try to resync package index list by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then try to install jpedTran:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg-turbo-progs
```